# Is it possible to have multiple gh pages for one repo?

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying to host multiple project pages using my repo to help build my porfolio. I have created multiple branches with their own index.html and corresponding css and js files so host on gh pages.

I have tried giving the pages unique domain names but the domain check always fails.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub pages are per a specific branch in your repository, so you cannot have multiple gh-pages that are live for one repository.

[Source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)

You can have different flavors of your gh-page on different branches and publish each flavor from it's respective branch.